# Matlab solve function

Tags: matlab

I'm working with a system of quadratic equations, my experiment has to go different lines from an initial distance Dist (1) and reach a distance 0.

The problem is that this code only reaches a minimum of approximately 0.00025.

It is a limitation of the solve function? or am I doing something wrong?

Of course, thank you very much.

Here is the code:

function SolveEcu()

```
xg = 0.229;
yg = 0.348;

ug = 0.136;
vg = 0.466;


i=1;
Dist(i) = 0.001; %Distancia inicial.

while Dist(i) > 0
    syms ucTemp vcTemp        
    S = solve(vcTemp == (-0.1209*ucTemp) + 0.4827, Dist(i)^2 == ((ucTemp-ug)^2+(vcTemp-vg)^2), 'Real', true); %Resuelvo el sistema de ecuaciones

    uTemp = S.ucTemp;% Lo uso para evaluar
    vTemp = S.vcTemp;
    save(['E:\Labz\Experimento Color\Resultados\',datestr(now,'yymmdd')],'uTemp','vTemp','Dist');

    i=i+1;   
    Dist(i)=Dist(i-1)- 0.00001;

    disp(['Running.. i=',num2str(i)])
end
pause(0.5);
end
```

---

Dist(i) = 2.5000e-04

Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.

> In solve at 169
>     In SolveEcu at 18 
>   Comma separated list expansion has cell syntax for
>   an array that
>   is not a cell.

Error in sym/subsref (line 1575)
            [inds{k},refs{k}] =
            privformat(inds{k});

Error in SolveEcu (line 20)
        uTemp = S.ucTemp;% Lo uso para evaluar

Comment: Have a look to [mldivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do not understand how this function could help me with my system of equations.

Any clues?

Comment: I look to your equation system and mldivide can't be apply. Because you cannot really make matrix with this. But about solve, I don't know let me look at it a bit.